# From the regular expression extractor using -1 for getting all matches, and from that how to choose the last one as a match in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

Whatever may to the total number of matching outcomes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your variable is `a` use [__V](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) for getting last occurrence using

```
${__V(a_${a_matchNr})}
```

or [__evalVar](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__evalVar)

```
${__evalVar(a_${a_matchNr})}
```

[a_matchNr](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) return last number

> refName_matchNr - the number of matches found; could be 0

Answer (score 0):

As per [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) documentation:

> If the match number is set to a negative number, then all the possible matches in the sampler data are processed. The variables are set as follows:
>
> `refName_matchNr` - the number of matches found; could be 0
>
> `refName_n`, where n = 1, 2, 3 etc. - the strings as generated by the template
>
> `refName_n_gm`, where m=0, 1, 2 - the groups for match n
>
> `refName` - always set to the default value
>
> `refName_gn` - not set

So the total number of matches is being stored in `${refName_matchNr}` JMeter Variable

If you want to get the last match dynamically you can use [__V() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) like:

```
${__V(refName_${refName_matchNr})}
```

Replace `refName` with your own JMeter Variable reference name

More information: [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables)